# AIF WebService AX 2009 - Service Address

Tags: web-services, ax, aif

I try to setup AIF WebService in AX 2009. I want to publish service in Internet. AX generated wsdl file well but he used local name of server. When client from cloud wants resolve server name to create proxy classes I get error can't find host. How can I change ax4aif.domain.local to IP address or how to setup AIF to publich services in Internet?

here I uploaded screenshot
https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=0AE7867F90F4DB32&id=AE7867F90F4DB32%21257

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't AIF. You need to expose your IIS application to the outside world.

https://serverfault.com/questions/311956/how-to-expose-iis-to-intranet-hosted-on-windows-server-2008-r2